# generate same random permutation on every computer

Tags: c++, random

I am using `random_shuffle` on sequence `a` 1000 times. I want to ensure that on every computer the final sequence is same. This might look undesirable, but still I want to achieve this. Does `srand(x)` ensure that ?

Comment: Why are you using random shuffle if you want the outcome to be always the same?

Comment: Does same and random go together? It will be interesting to see the answer :)

Comment: Yes, if you pick the same seed you'' get the same sequence.

Comment: Why do you it 1000 times? This smells like an http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @JameyD but then does it remain "random" if it gives the same answer?

Comment: @sami1592 - that's why these things are formally known as **pseudo**-random number generators.

Comment: @EdHeal - this is quite common; it's why the specifications of the random number engines in C++11 include detailed algorithms and, in many cases, the value of the 10,000th number generated from a particular seed. It's useful for testing that implementations on different platforms in fact produce the same result, which raises confidence in software that will be used in massively-parallel Monte Carlo simulations. The C++11 random stuff mostly came out of Fermi-lab, where they do a great deal of simulation of complex physical systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two sources of differences in the resulting shuffle: the algorithm for `rand()` is not specified, so different implementations produce different sequences of numbers; and the algorithm for `random_shuffle` is not specified, so, again, different implementations produce different results, even with the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers.

You can eliminate the first problem by using any of the random-number generators in C++11; they're all specified in detail, including, for some specializations, a requirement for the 10,000th value, which is a **great** help in debugging their implementation. However, there's no analog for shuffling. In particular, the algorithm for `std::shuffle` is not specified, so it won't give reproducible results. You'll have to write your own. That's not difficult (nowhere near as difficult as writing an engine), just do a little research; there are lots of discussion out there for you to start from.

Comment: A common shuffling algorithm is the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle).